# Workflow moving file and retaining meta data (can't copy/paste/delete)?

Tags: 2007, workflow

As an unfortunate consequence of poor planning the system I work on has a reliance on meta data (date created, date modified) for some reporting. Although we're currently in the process of phasing this out we have a more pressing need to archive items for end of financial year.

With this in mind I was planning on writing a workflow that would archive content, once it's updated from one site collection to another.

My question is - SharePoint workflows only support copy/paste/delete which means that the file gets a new date created. Without having to store this data in a database or in the file is there a way I can retain the original date created or alternatively move the content instead of re-creating and then removing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a set of SharePoint designer activities that can help with this. Alternatively you can create a new activity that assists with this.  Here is the link to the project.
http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/

other than this or going to a 3rd party workflow i don't know of any other way to accomplish.